# active tab indicator line under tab button, how does it move?

Tags: css, tabs

Looking at [google translate](https://translate.google.com/) tab buttons for example, when we click on a language the blue line under that language moves from the preivous one the currently clicked one.

In the css I can see a class is removed/added to the active/inactive tabs buttons, which controls `opacity` for a `span` inside the button, and setting that `opacity` manually makes the line appear, **but** doesn't animate anything.

Also if I set `overflow:hidden` on the span containing the line, the animation won't start from the previous tab button anymore, but I don't see any `right` or `left` being set by js, so something else has to be used.

Anybody knows the secret behind this line moving when a tab button is clicked?

Comment: Sounds like there is javascript involved.

Comment: @Paulie_D yes, but I can't find what css properties is the js setting

Comment: Show us the javascript and we might be able to help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you meant something like this.

```js
function moveLine(button) {
  var tabButtons = document.querySelectorAll('.tab-button');
  var line = document.querySelector('.line');

  // Remove 'active' class from all buttons
  tabButtons.forEach(function(tabButton) {
    tabButton.classList.remove('active');
  });

  // Add 'active' class to the clicked button
  button.classList.add('active');

  // Calculate the left position of the active button
  var activeButtonRect = button.getBoundingClientRect();
  var containerRect = button.parentNode.getBoundingClientRect();
  var offsetLeft = activeButtonRect.left - containerRect.left;

  // Apply the transform to move the line
  line.style.transform = 'translateX(' + offsetLeft + 'px)';
}
```

```css
.tab-container {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
}

.tab-button {
  background: none;
  border: none;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  font-size: 16px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: opacity 0.3s;
}

.tab-button.active {
  opacity: 1;
}

.line {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
  height: 3px;
  background-color: blue;
  transition: transform 0.3s;
}

body {
  background-color: aqua;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="tab-container">
    <button class="tab-button active" onclick="moveLine(this)">Button 1</button>
    <button class="tab-button" onclick="moveLine(this)">Button 2</button>
    <button class="tab-button" onclick="moveLine(this)">Button 3</button>
    <div class="line"></div>
  </div>
  <script src="app.js "></script>
</body>

</html>
```